# Does PHP guarantee the order of array values in $_GET?

Tags: php, html, arrays, query-string

[HTML guarantees the order](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) of form fields when they are encoded on submit, which means this form:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input name="Foo[]" value="one">
    <input name="Foo[]" value="two">
    <input name="Foo[]" value="three">
</form>
```

will always be encoded into this query string:

```
?Foo[]=one&Foo[]=two&Foo[]=three
```

But here's my question. When PHP pulls these values into `$_GET['Foo']` *does PHP guarantee the order* of the array? Meaning, given that query string, will the value of `Foo` always equal:

```
array('one', 'two', 'three'); //?
```

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP Manual's [FAQ on PHP and HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays):

> To get your `<form>` result sent as an array to your PHP script you name the `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` elements like this:

```
    <input name="MyArray[]" />
    <input name="MyArray[]" />
    <input name="MyArray[]" />
    <input name="MyArray[]" />
```

Answer in bold:

> Specifying an arrays key is optional in HTML. **If you do not specify the keys, the array gets filled in the order the elements appear in the form.** Our first example will contain keys 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: is there a reason you haven't accepted this answer?